# Unable to add generated pkpass to iPhone using MobileSafari

Tags: php, ios, json, passbook

I am generating a .pkpass with a PHP library, [PHP-PKPass](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass), but the problem is, I cannot add it to my phone with MobileSafari, it throws:

```
Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.bittank.kidstation/1243. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
```

I have the appropriate certs (Certificate.p12, WWDCRA.pem)
Typically, this error means that the certificates are missing, but it isn't true.

```
<?php

//if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    // User has filled in the card info, so create the pass now

    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    require('../src/PKPass.php');

    // Variables
    $id = rand(100000,999999) . '-' . rand(100,999) . '-' . rand(100,999); // Every card should have a unique serialNumber
    $balance = '$'.rand(0,30).'.'.rand(10,99); // Create random balance
    $name = stripslashes($_GET['name']);
    $children = stripslashes($_GET['children']);
    $date = stripslashes($_GET['date']);
    $allergies = stripslashes($_GET['allergies']);
    // Create pass
$pass = new PKPass\PKPass();

    $pass->setCertificate('../Certificate.p12');  // 2. Set the path to your Pass Certificate (.p12 file)
$pass->setCertificatePassword('password');     // 2. Set password for certificate
$pass->setWWDRcertPath('../WWDCRA.pem'); // 3. Set the path to your WWDR Intermediate certificate (.pem file)

    $pass->setJSON('{ 
    "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.bittank.kidstation",
    "formatVersion": 1,
    "organizationName": "Kid Station",
    "teamIdentifier": "Z48RKT6B3T",
    "serialNumber": "1243",
    "expirationDate": "'.$date.'",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,240,240)",
    "logoText": "Kid Station",
    "description": "Demo pass",
    "storeCard": {
        "secondaryFields": [
            {
                "key": "balance",
                "label": "Children",
                "value": "'.$children.'"
            },
            {
                "key": "name",
                "label": "Parent",
                "value": "'.$name.'"
            }

        ],
        "backFields" : [
        {
            "key" : "special-concerns",
            "label" : "Special Concerns",
            "value" : "'.$allergies.'"
        },
        {
            "key" : "website",
            "label" : "Track my checked bags",
            "value" : "http://www.example.com/track-bags/XYZ123"
        },
        {
            "key" : "customer-service",
            "label" : "Customer service",
            "value" : "(800) 555-0199"
        },
        {
            "key" : "terms",
            "label" : "Terms and Conditions",
            "value" : "O Fortuna velut luna statu variabilis, semper crescis aut decrescis; vita detestabilis nunc obdurat et tunc curat ludo mentis aciem, egestatem, potestatem dissolvit ut glaciem.\n\n Sors immanis et inanis, rota tu volubilis, status malus, vana salus semper dissolubilis, obumbrata et velata michi quoque niteris; nunc per ludum dorsum nudum fero tui sceleris.\n\n Sors salutis et virtutis michi nunc contraria, est affectus et defectus semper in angaria.  Hac in hora sine mora corde pulsum tangite; quod per sortem sternit fortem, mecum omnes plangite!"
        }
    ]


    },
    "barcode": {
        "format": "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
        "message": "'.$id.'",
        "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
        "altText": "'.$id.'"
    }
    }');

    // add files to the PKPass package
    $pass->addFile('icon.png');
    $pass->addFile('icon@2x.png');
    $pass->addFile('logo.png');
    $pass->addFile('background.png', 'strip.png');

    if(!$pass->create(true)) { // Create and output the PKPass
        echo 'Error: '.$pass->getError();
    }
    exit;

//*}else{
    // User lands here, there are no $_POST variables set   
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Starbucks pass creator - PHP class demo</title>

            <!-- Reusing some CSS from another project of mine -->
            <link href="http://www.lifeschool.nl/static/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                .header { background-color: #CCC; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px; margin-bottom: 32px; text-align: center; }
                .logo { width: 84px; height: 84px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
                .title { color: black; font-size: 22px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: center; }
                .userinfo { margin: 0px auto; padding-bottom: 32px; width: 280px;}
                form.form-stacked { padding: 0px;}
                legend { text-align: center; padding-bottom: 25px; border-bottom: none; clear: both;}
                input.xlarge { width: 280px; height: 26px; line-height: 26px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <img class="logo" src="logo_web.png" />
                <span class="title">Starbucks</span>
            </div>
            <div class="userinfo">
                <form action="index.php" method="post" class="form-stacked">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="padding-left: 0px;">Please enter your info</legend>

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <label style="text-align:left">Nickname</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="xlarge" name="name" type="text" value="Johnny's card" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br /><br />
                <center><input type="submit" class="btn primary" value=" Create pass &gt; " /></center>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?
//}
```

EDIT (more info for @PassKit)

Here is my certificate I am using:
[image: KeyChain]
[image: Cert]
[image: ID]

Comment: Did you set up your pass type identifier in the Apple Developer Portal and generate your certificate from there?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, I did. You need a screenshot?

Comment: A link to your .pkpass bundle or just the signature file would be helpful.

Comment: @PassKit http://pass.keatonburleson.com/pass/starbucks_sample/index.php?name=Fredrick&date=2015-08-19T15:00-08:00&children=Pam&allergies=Death

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at your signature in a Hex Editor, your problem appears to be that you are not signing with a Pass Type ID certificate.  Specifically, you have signed with an `Apple Development IOS Push Services` certificate,  `com.bittank.kidstation`.  All valid Pass Type ID certificates start with `pass.`  E.g. `pass.com.bittank.kidstation`.

[image: Hex Editer Screenshot]

To create a Pass Type ID certificate is a 2 stage process (correct at time of posting):

First, create a Pass Type ID using the **Identifiers** option on the left of the '*Certificates, Identities and Profiles*' page in the Apple Developer Portal.

[image: Apple Developer Portal]

Second, use the **Certificates** section to create the certificate by choosing '*Pass Type ID Certificate*' under the **Production** section.  It is important to note that there are no development certificates for Passbook.

[image: Apple Developer Portal]

When you examine a valid Pass Type ID certificate in Finder, you should see that the certificate common name starts with *Pass Type ID:*

[image: Valid Pass Type ID Certificate]

Comment: thanks for the insight, I just added more information pertaining to what you said. I see nothing amiss, just curious why it would be doing this.

Comment: I think you may need to double check the process you used to get from the pass.cer that you downloaded to the certificate.p12 file you are using in your code.  There is no question that your pass bundle has been signed with a push certificate (and not the certificate you are showing above).  At a guess, I would say you have exported the wrong certificate from your keychain.

Comment: I'll remove all and start fresh and then report back .

Comment: Also, look at your p12 file with Finder's quick look.  This should confirm whether you have successfully exported it.